# Sharing variables across threads

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

already tried to solve my issue via existing posts - however, did not manage to. Thx for your help in advance.

The objective is to share a variable across threads. Please find below the code. It keeps printing '1' for the accounting variable, although I want it to print '2'. Any suggestions why?

**main.py**:

```
account = 1

import threading
import cfg
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_cfg = threading.Thread(target=cfg.global_cfg(),args= ())
    thread_cfg.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(account)
```

**cfg.py**:

```
def global_cfg():
    global account
    account = 2
    return()
```

Comment: globals are not across files

Comment: Also note: This line of code does not do what you think it does: `thread_cfg = threading.Thread(target=cfg.global_cfg(),args= ())`. It immediately _calls_ `cfg.global_cfg()` from the main thread, and then it creates a new thread that does nothing. You're telling the `Thread()` constructor that the `target` of the new thread should be whatever is returned by _calling_ `global_cfg()`.  If you want the target to _be_ `global.cfg`, then just use the name of that function for the target. `threading.Thread(target=cfg.global_cfg,args= ())`

Comment: @SolomonSlow oh yeah I removed it automatically in my answer, didn't notice. My brain  is wired to fix stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are not shared across files.

If we disregard locks and other synchronization primitives, just put `account` inside `cfg.py`:

```
account = 1
def global_cfg():
    global account
    account = 2
    return
```

And inside `main.py`:

```
import threading
import time
import cfg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_cfg = threading.Thread(target=cfg.global_cfg,args= ())
    print(cfg.account)
    thread_cfg.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(cfg.account)
```

Running it:

```
> py main.py
1
2
```

---

In more advanced cases, you should use `Lock`s, `Queue`s and other structures, but that's out of scope.